# Upgrade Apache Hbase hadoop 0.94 to 1.0.0, override map method compilation file

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, cloudera-cdh

In version org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result class version 0.94 implements Writable interface.
We use it for override general mapper methods in order to support different data sources (Hbase is one of them)
Currently we try to upgrade Hbase client version and we have following problem:
The org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result class of Hbase 1.0.0 does not implements Writable interface, so we have problem to use our old Mapper override method that receive writable interface as one of parameters. 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply compile your program with latest API jar, better compile you code entirely in the new environment with all latest jars from hadoop as well, because Hbase new versions are not compatible with hadoop old versions as well. Problem is that the new HBase implementation has renamed few of the classes, which are internally referred by other API classes. Even though you do not import them directly, the program fails at runtime.

We faced the same Writable issue when upgraded 0.94 to 0.98

Comment: Thank you, I use lasted recommended version:
 hadoop-common version:2.6.0-cdh5.4.5    hbase-client  version:2.6.0-cdh5.4.5. The reason of problem it's changed of implementation hierarchy of Result class, The change was in hbase client 0.95, If you solve this problem looks like you did additional thing.